# Table View - Remove Cell Opacity

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have a tableView that has a black background with an opacity of 10%. That is to give it a "boxed" look to separate it from the rest of the view. For some reason, each CELL is also adding a semi-transparent background (visible in the second screenshot) and each string of text is ALSO adding the same thing (this is visible in the screenshot if you look closely enough).

[image]

[image: 2]

For example, notice around "Sandwich Hot Turkey" how it is darker behind the text than it is to the right of the text.

How do I get rid of that for each cell and each string?

Comment: have you tried with cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; ?

Comment: That solves the problem pictured, but not the other problem. Let me post a screenshot of the other. Thanks!

Comment: Second screenshot has the other problem. Question updated to reflect that as well.

Comment: Just tried cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; and that did not work.

Comment: what's your second problem? If you do not want to see the background set the table background to clearColor.

Comment: The second problem is how each individual cell has a "tint" to it for the background, on top of what the entire tableView has. See second screenshot. I want the tableView to have a background, just not each cell.

Comment: James, Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue with the cell having a semi transparent view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];` and `cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];`

and try with `cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];` to set the content of the cell transparent.

Comment: That's what I used to get the second screenshot.